# Stata panel data: egen =total() over period starting with a given date

Tags: date, sum, panel, stata

My data are structured as follows (`dataex` output at the end, but it is confusing since it only shows the numeric time expressions):

```
id yearmo birthmo smoke surveytime health
1 2002m1  2003m11  0.8  0  .
1 2002m2  2003m11  0.7  0  .
[...]
1 2004m1  2003m11  0.5  1  "good"
```

I merged a panel data set containing yearly survey information (e.g. on my dependent variable `health`) with monthly information on smoking exposure (numeric). My time variable `yearmo` contains the year and month and is in %tm format. `Birthmo` is the individual's birth month and year and has the same format.

I want to generate a variable containing the total smoke exposure during pregnancy, which is in the period `birthmo[_n-1], birthmo[_n-10]`.

Is it possible to use `egen prebirth_smoke = total(smoke)` and refer it to this time period? I couldn't find anything so far. But since it is possible to calculate time differences like `gen age2000 = (14610-birthday)/365.25` referring to a variable indicating the birthday, I thought there must be a solution for my problem as well...

My other approach would be to fill up the survey information for each month and use a command like `by persnr: egen prebirth_smoke=total(smoke, smoke[_n-10]) if birthmo = moyear`. Then I would have to copy this information to each month of the year again and collapse the data to yearly information. Is there any easier way?

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input double persnr float(moyear birthmo surveytime) double smoke
23908 504   . 0  23.96554252199413
23908 505   . 0 16.531705948372615
23908 506   . 0 19.731182795698928
23908 507   . 0 15.172916666666667
23908 508   . 0 12.199596774193546
23908 509   . 0 12.218055555555557
23908 510   . 0 10.207416911045943
23908 511   . 0  11.54166666666667
23908 512   . 0 14.311111111111112
23908 513   . 0 16.728005865102638
23908 514   . 0 22.759722222222226
23908 515   . 0  21.10752688172043
23908 516 515 1 27.638440860215056
23908 517 515 1 24.914434523809522
23908 518 515 1 22.103515874027796
23908 519 515 1 16.881249999999998
23908 520 515 1  14.51930596285435
23908 521 515 1 10.573909068193176
23908 522 515 1 10.057123655913978
23908 523 515 1   12.2486559139785
end
format %tm moyear
format %tm birthmo
```

Comment: sorry, I was sure I wrote a greeting before telling my problem!

Comment: Some greetings are automatically removed. Greetings and thanks are not used in Stack Overflow as we stick to just factual coding questions and answers and avoid the chit-chat.

Comment: Honestly, i had to run the `dataex` code to understand what you mean in your first table...

Comment: Note that `sum()` in `generate` and `egen` calculates different things. In the former, it calculates the running sum of a variable, whereas in the latter the combined sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for your example data:

```
egen BIRTHMO = mean(birthmo), by(persnr) 
egen exposure = total(inrange(BIRTHMO - moyear, 1, 10) * smoke), by(persnr)
```

For a survey of related technique, see https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055

Small points:

1. There is nothing confusing about the `dataex` code. The point is that its implications are clear once you run it.
2. Your `egen` code wouldn't work, even in spirit.   The `total()` argument is illegal. Typo: second `=` should be `==`. Warning: the `help` for `egen` is explicit about not using subscripted expressions.
3. `egen, sum()` is undocumented as of Stata 9. Best to use and refer to `total()`. The code is equivalent, but that still holds.

Comment: I can't remember when was the last time i saw `sum()` used in `egen`. I think it is still available probably for backward compatibility reasons.

Comment: It's still there, but as said undocumented.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, thanks @Nick Cox.
I edited the topic for consistency. I accidentally wrote Sum() instead of total().